# Trying to get property of non-object PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I know that this question in the tittle is asked WAYY too much in here, and I went thru most of them but still cant find a solution for my code.

```
function calculatingWages($project_id){
    $start_date = '2017-05-01';
    $end_date = '2017-12-31';

    $project = Project::find($project_id);
    $users = $project->users()->get();

    $sumWage=0;
    foreach ($users as $user){
        $timesheetHours = $user->timesheets()->whereBetween('timesheets.date',[$start_date,$end_date])->sum('hours');
        $wages = UserWage::whereBetween('start_date',[ $start_date,$end_date])->whereBetween('end_date',[ $start_date,$end_date])->get();

        foreach ($wages as $wage){

            $value = $wage->value;
            $currency = $wage->currency;
            $sumWage =   extractMonthsAndCalculate($value,$currency, $timesheetHours, $start_date, $end_date);
        }
        return $sumWage;
    }
}

function extractMonthsAndCalculate($value,$currency, $timesheetHours, $start_date, $end_date){
    $start = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$start_date)->month;
    $end = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$end_date)->month;

    $diffOfMonths = $end - $start;
    $sumWage = 0;
    for ($i = $start; $i <= $diffOfMonths; $i++) {
        $wageYear  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$start_date)->year;

        $wageDay = Carbon::createFromDate($wageYear,$i,'01')->lastOfMonth()->toDateString();
       $test =  convertingALL($value,$currency,$timesheetHours,$wageDay);
    }
    return $sumWage;
}

function convertingALL($value, $currency, $timesheetHours, $date)
{
    $currencyObj = Exchange::where('date',$date)->get()->first();
    $currencyDate = $currencyObj->date;

     $hourlyWage = 0;

    $sumWage = 0;
    if($currencyDate == $date) {

        $dollar = $currencyObj->dollar_lek;
        $euro = $currencyObj->euro_lek;

        if ($currency == 'ALL') {
            $sumWage = $value;
        } elseif ($currency == 'USD') {
            $sumWage = ($hourlyWage *$timesheetHours) * $dollar;
        } else {
            $sumWage = ($hourlyWage *$timesheetHours)* $euro;
        }
   }else{
        $euro = 140;
        $dollar = 136.4;

        if ($currency == 'ALL') {
            $sumWage = $value;
        } elseif ($currency == 'USD') {
            $sumWage = $value * $dollar;
        } else {
            $sumWage = $value * $euro;
        }
    }
    return $sumWage;
}
```

it says that it cant get the property of a non object in line 468

this is line 467-468:

```
$currencyObj = Exchange::where('date',$date)->get()->first();
    $currencyDate = $currencyObj->date;
```

when I dd $currencyDate  it prints the date of it, tried to parse it using carbon but still same thing, where am I messing up?

Comment: Why are you doing `->get()->first()`. Usually you use only one.

Comment: I think your not handling the data properly. You will probably need to use date in a different way then a regular object. I think you problem is to do with the way your handling date. Search into it ...

Comment: @Jackowski there might be two dates with same date, so I want to get only 1 of them

Comment: Given the error, `$currencyObj = Exchange::where('date',$date)->get()->first();` isn’t giving you an object, so `dd()` and see what the result of _that_ is before trying to get properties off of it.

Comment: @WebGuy can you enlighten me a bit more please?

Comment: @MartinBean `Exchange {#414 ▼
  #fillable: array:3 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null`, and if I dd currencyDate it prints the date

Comment: Something more like this:  `$this->attributes['start_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('M/d/Y', $date)->format('Y-m-d');`

Reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/working-with-dates-in-laravel-carbon?page=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Eloquent that the `date` field contains a date (even though it seems obvious).

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

---

In your `Exchange` model you should have

```
class Exchange extends Model {

    protected $dates = [ 'date' ];
```

---

On an unrelated note, `->get()->first()` will pull every single result back from the database, then chuck all but one of them away. If you just call `->first()` then you'll only get one result from the database; same end result but better for performance.

Comment: I've added date at fillables

Comment: if I add what you said, and remove it from fillables I get `Trailing data`. same result if I keep it in fillables too

Comment: @BTEK I didn't say to put it in $fillable ;-)